# Angular 2 using filter with JSON

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

My problem is that I want use number filter in place of string filter. What will be line of code?

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

import {index} from './index';

@Pipe({
    name:'bookFilter',
})

export class BookFilterPipe implements PipeTransform

{

    transform(value:index[],filterBy:any):index[]
    {
        filterBy=filterBy?filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase():null;
        return filterBy?value.filter((book:index)=>  

        book.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy)!==-1):value  
        // here I want to use year filter in that line. 
       // like **book.year**       what will be full line of code in that place
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail what do you want to acheive . you want to filter a bunch of words

Comment: Actually, i have a data in table in which [ S.n, Name, Amount , Year ] is columns. i want to filter table by year wise. I used dropdown button in   which mention 2010 to 2017 years. So i want when i select one year Like 2010 then all data of 2010 year should be come in table.